# Come around to you (yours) or come around to your place

Tags: phrase-usage

I did a google search for 'come around to you' , 'come around to yours', 'come around to your place'. The results do not seem satisfactory. Do you say 'come around to you (me)'? Is this phrasing correct?

The phrasing 'come around to your place' sounds somewhat unnarural or very formal. I can't imagine that someone could say something like that in infomal conversation.

Some examples:

> I remember your invitation last week. I'll come around to yours for supper today.

:

> [Longman dictinaries](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/come_1) come around:to come to someone's home or the place where they work in order to visit them

Comment: "come around to" or "come over to " are colloquial for "come to".  However, in AmE I never have heard come/come around/come over "to yours"; it's always "to your house" or "to your place". As for "come around/over to you":  that would be "come around/over to SEE you"

Comment: "Yours" for "your home/place" seems to be fairly widespread in the UK now, though 10 or 20 years ago I'd've said it was a Liverpool/Irish expression.

Comment: ... to continue: I've just heard Valerie Holiday [born Newark, NJ] talking on UK radio about forming The Three Degrees.  She said they were talking to some people and "went round to theirs."

Comment: well, in America anyway—and who knows but what the UK version "around to yours" might be infiltrating America as well?  I'm only in one little corner of it.

Answer (score 2):

In the U.K., I hear "Come round to my place." much more than "Come **a**round...", but both are used.

Also used are: "Come round to mine", "I'm going round to the neighbour's." etc. "Come over" is also used as in: "Put the kettle on, I'm coming over to your place."

"Come **a**round" appears more commonly with two other meanings:

- To wake from unconsciousness.
- To move from an opposing or undecided position to one of agreement. e.g. "Having been against the idea, John came around to Tim's point of view."