# How to use the prepositions "apud" and "chez"?

Tags: prepositions, american-english, british-english, latin, french

I couldn't find many examples of *apud* and *chez* as prepositions; I just found one description on Wiktionary:

> **[apud](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apud)**
>   1. Used in scholarly works to cite a reference at second hand.
>
> - Jones **apud** Smith means that the original source is Jones, but that the author is relying on Smith for that reference.

More shockingly, I found nine meanings of apud on [Word Hippo site](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-meaning-of/latin-word-4b004d8dd1bd23f44634d684ef274a77f626eb15.html), i.e. among, at, before, amongst, about, beside, near, in the presence of.

The next word is **[chez](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chez)**, meaning "at the home of." Again from Wiktionary:

> - 2008 February 28, Lisa Forest, “Mind the gap: Empty house, empty nest, empty fridge”, in *The Telegraph*:
>
> > > Even if I say so myself, Christmas **chez** the Forests is quite a heart-warming affair. For Ben, growing up, it was pure magic – a log fire in the grate, ...

Also, are these two words not used in English, but in Greek, Latin, or French? I found *apud* and *chez* in a **[Wikipedia article with a list of English prepositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_prepositions)**.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80829/discussion-on-question-by-iqbal-ahmed-siyal-how-to-use-the-prepositions-apud-a).

Comment: How many answers does one need? lol @james

Comment: @James Wolpert - what part of the question still needs more attention?

Comment: @Gio, I have added more research in my body of question; I said: "More shockingly, I found nine meanings of apud on Word Hippo site, i.e. among, at, before, amongst, about, beside, near, in the presence of."

Comment: @user, please read my comment above.

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal - you accepted an answer  and that suggests  that you are set with your question.

Comment: @user070221 but the bounty is awarded by the benefactor, in this case, user James Wolpert.

Comment: Iqbal Ahmed Siyal I'm sorry to point out what you can find in one or two references is not at all the same as what matters.

In 60 years of listening I have never once noticed "apud" nor anything remotely like that. I suggest that wherever you found it, it has no place in English.

Similarly, "chez" is pure French and even more clearly has no place in English.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Regarding **apud**, I would advise against using such an obscure term. Unless it is common in the specific publication you are writing for.

[Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Documentation/faq0197.html):

> Q. When can we use apud in a note?
>
> A. Apud (Latin for “at,” “beside,” “within”) precedes the name of an author or title to indicate a source. It is used like the French word chez to mean “in the works of” or “according to”: apud Homer. It’s appropriate for those occasions when you just want to impress classics teachers or elderly readers and it doesn’t really matter whether anyone else understands.

Publications' style guides may provide rules on how one should cite an indirect reference. For example: [How to Cite a Reference Within a Reference in APA Format](https://penandthepad.com/cite-within-reference-apa-format-6040355.html)

---

[**Chez** was added to the question after I posted the above]

I think **chez** would be widely understood by (native) English speakers even if they wouldn't use it often. According to [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/chez):

> Used Occasionally. chez is one of the 30000 most commonly used words in the Collins dictionary

With a nice little graph showing an odd peak in the mid 1700s.

Their definition is:

> 1. at the home of
> 2. with, among, or in the manner of
>
> Example: *London is busy letting its hair down but all is obviously not well chez Belmont.* Edward Docx THE CALLIGRAPHER (2003)

It *can* seem pretentious and so is sometimes used for humorous effect or ironically.

Comment: You might want to clarify that this refers to *apud*, not *chez*. (And I agree about its obscurity; I edited a scholarly journal *for classicists* for almost a decade and never saw it used in a single article.)

Comment: @1006a That’s quite surprising to me! I’ve seen it used dozens of times in journal articles, though admittedly ones aimed at historical/comparative linguists rather than classicists as such. Still, a fair amount of overlap between the two. I’ve always seen it as a perfectly common word to use in scholarly articles.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Perhaps it's a difference in sources? My journal is specifically focused on pedagogy, so the sources cited are mostly modern—I would guess that would mean less need for *apud* (since the original sources are usually extant) but also perhaps the Latin just looks more natural when the sources cited are also in ancient languages? My "day job" is in the social sciences, and I'd call *apud* rare-to-nonexistent there (even in law, which typically loves Latin).

Comment: @1006a I don’t even think it’s more prevalent in Classical sources than in modern ones in my field—it’s perfectly normal to see something like “Kuryłowicz _apud_ Matasović (2006)”, for example (referring to [Jerzy Kuryłowicz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerzy_Kuryłowicz)).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, our house style was based on MLA, which specifies "qtd. in", so perhaps our authors were aware of that (though judging by other citation...issues I wouldn't have thought they were all looking up the specifications while writing). In general, of course, "go with your publication's preferred style" is usually the answer for this kind of thing.

Comment: @JamesRandom Do you mind just adding the entire question from the Chicago Manual of Style? No one else has and it has helpful definitions, comparisons, and examples, even if the note ends by advising against using it at all.

Comment: @lly Good idea!

Answer (score 14):

Note that, to answer your question, we cannot define the obscurity of *apud*, as it itself seems unimportant to be defined here.

And, we shouldn't say that *apud* has become an English word. *Apud* is simply a Latin word that is surrounded by the words of English. Seeing that this word is defined in [*Latin Dictionary*](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/preposition:apud), not in Cambridge, M. Webster or Oxford Dictionary, the Latin Dictionary gives its meaning: next to or at.

However, *chez* has been defined in various English dictionaries. *[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chez)* defines it as under:

> at or in the home or business place of

#### Origin and Etymology:

> French, from Latin *casa* cottage

#### First known use:

> 1940

*Chez* has *also* been defined in [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Chez), [English Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chez) and [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/chez).

### Usage:

> 1. They had had a superb party **chez** John yesterday. [=they had had a superb party **at the house of** John yesterday.
> 2. We live **chez** my best friend. [=we live **at the house of** my best friend]

To cap it all, we cannot compare *apud* with *chez* and *chez* with *apud*, as its meaning is somehow not interchangeable, and they differ drastically in their origin.

Comment: @1006a, I did it, as you said. Thanks for this advice.

Comment: @JamesWolpert I really thought it was a cool, probably a little archaic usage, you could have fooled me!

Comment: @JoshRumbut, I just related it to bullfighting. Interestingly, in bullfighting, cape as a verb means to taunt (the bull) by flourishing a cape. See here: https://www.spanish-fiestas.com/culture/bullfighting-history/

Answer (score 6):

*Chez* is a French word meaning '*at* the home of'. I believe 'apud' means the same in Latin. There is no single word with the same meaning in English, so we have to use phrases like 'at our house' or 'at the Smiths' home'. English speakers familiar with the French word sometimes use it in English to express the idea in one word.

Comment: Yes, right. It can also extend to someone's oeuvre, but let's leave that one for the swamp people (joke).

Comment: @Lambie Unless the joke was about using yet another French word, it went way over my head.

Comment: *Apud* can mean the same as *chez*, but its use in Latin is much more extensive, meaning “near” or “next to”, see [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dapud)

Comment: @MrLister Probably a reference to "frogs".

Comment: Where *at* can take a non-pronominal possessive (“Didn’t I see you over at Mary’s?”, never “Didn’t I see you over at ✽hers?”), *chez* always takes an unmarked noun (“Didn’t I see you chez Mary?“) not a possessive form.

Comment: @MrLister In French, chez can be used to refer to an author or his/her work (**oeuvre**), la métaphique chez Kant.....metaphysics in Kant.....is etc.

Comment: @egreg, while it is true that *apud* in Latin has a wide range of uses (some of which overlap the uses of *chez* in French), in English contexts, it is used only for the very narrow purpose outlined in a couple of other answers.

Comment: @jsw29 Right, but the answer says *apud* means in Latin the same as French *chez*, which is far from true. It means the same in *English*. Because of “I believe”, I thought some remark was needed.

Comment: @tchrist What’s wrong with “Didn’t I see you over at hers?”? _At_ is perfectly happy to take pronominal possessives to me (“She stayed at ours for a while”, “D’you wanna come round to mine?”, etc.). Did you mean to say that where _at_ always takes a possessive, _chez_ never does?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It just needs an obvious antecedent, is all. Me, I've never used *chez* with a possessive. It seems funny. But I may be mixing languages here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet “Didn’t I see you over at hers?” would only ever be used in a specific context, e.g. "Why does she say you can't come to my place? Didn’t I see you over at hers?”

Comment: @Chappo That particular sentence requires a fairly specific context, yes; but that’s down to the sentence as a whole, not the _at_ + possessive pronoun construction. The other two examples I gave are fine with no particularly specific context.

Comment: @tchrist No, I agree: _chez_ with a possessive (noun or pronoun) sounds strange. And it sounds odd with a pronoun too, now that I think about it. So really, we should say that while _at_ always takes a possessive (noun or pronoun), _chez_ can only take unmarked nouns.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet perhaps it's regional. To me as a native Australian speaker, the other two would sound equally confusing or weird if they weren't preceded by a previous reference to someone else's place, home, city etc.

Comment: @Chappo That’s interesting. It may be that it’s mainly BrE ([this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227523) definitely confirms that it is used in BrE, so I’m not just imagining it); I never really thought about that.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think you might be right, the usage sounds vaguely British to me. Like "I've not" vs "I haven't". You gotta love the complexity of English!

Answer (score 5):

**Apud** is not used extensively enough in English to be considered an English word. For instance, it is not included in the *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED) as a *lemma*, that is as

> a form of a word that appears as **an entry in a dictionary** and is used to represent all the other possible forms ([Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lemma), my emphasis)

The 2nd edition of the OED contains "171,476 words in current use, and 47,156 obsolete words" (OED site).

*Apud* is also not included in most professionally compiled dictionaries of English. For instance, [OneLook](https://www.onelook.com/?w=apud&ls=a) shows no examples of such dictionaries containing the word. And the resources you have cited in your question are also not professionally compiled dictionaries (such as Merriam-Webster, Oxford, American Heritage, Collins, Websters, but not wiktionary). Others have stated that *apud* is used in formal works to mean *by means of*, or *through*; this is an extremely specialized usage: not enough, really to make it an "English word." Thus any definitions of it come from its use in native Latin.

The OED does contain a centuries old, obsolete English preposition/adverb called **anent**, used as far back as the year 1000, or the time of Old English. The reason I mention this is because for this *English* (but obsolete) word, the OED compares its various meanings with those of both *apud* and *chez* (and even the German *neben*), as in

> In the company of, with, among, beside, by (Latin *apud*, French *chez*, German *neben*)

also

> With (figuratively), according to the way or manner of (Latin *apud*)

also

> On a level with in position, rank, or value; equal to, on a par with

also

> In a line with, side by side with, in company with, beside

I am quoting definitions of the obsolete English word *anent* to show that such prepositions/adverbs can have several associated meanings (and also because I had never heard of it before and it seems a nifty word). I hope this helps explain the added concern in your question expressed by "More shockingly, I found nine meanings of apud on Word Hippo site, i.e. among, at, before, amongst, about, beside, near, in the presence of." Such words, whether in English or other languages such as Latin can indeed have a host of meanings.

But again, it is important to distinguish between professionally compiled dictionaries (such as Merriam-Webster, Oxford, American Heritage, Collins, Websters, but not wiktionary) that deal with English words and sources that might list words that are not usually considered to be English words, such as *apud*.

Take-home message:

> Despite the presence of *apud* in WordHippo, it is not an English word, and the multiple meanings there are really meanings that it has *in Latin*, not *in English*. 99% of English speakers have never heard of the word.

On the other hand...

**Chez**, as can be seen by the definition of *ament*, is one French equivalent of the Latin *apud*, with the difference that *chez,* like other borrowed words such as *gratis*, *rodeo* and *lasso*, has been used so often by native English speakers (in this case to mean "at the house or home of" (OED)) that it is considered an English word, and it appears as a lemma in the OED and several other good English dictionaries. See [OneLook](https://www.onelook.com/?w=chez&ls=a), for example. There you will find definitions in Merriam-Webster, Oxford, American Heritage, Collins, Websters, all of which are what I mean by professionally compiled dictionaries. Wiktionary is not included in that category and I highly, strongly suggest you do not rely on it; in fact, I suggest you as a learner don't use it.

Comment: Surely “lemma” need no longer be set in italics after nigh onto five centuries of use!

Comment: @user, very helpful answer of you.

Comment: @user, can we regard apud and chez as loan-words?

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal You *could* but he's saying that so far 'apud' *isn't*. It's simply Latin that is being used as shorthand by some people within English. 'Chez', on the other hand, has become an actual loanword/borrowing because of its repeated use within English. (All the same, I still see it treated as foreign and often see it set in italics, the way user is mistakenly treating lemma.)

Comment: I italicized, and even defined, lemma because that's what good writers often do when introducing a term that they think their audience might not be familiar with; it has nothing to do with *it* (lemma) being a "foreign" word. Granted, I also italicized it the second time I used it, but that was for the same reason; I have unitalicized my second use of it to keep the peanut gallery happy.

Answer (score 3):

From [this blog](http://www.brunocunha.com/blog/en/Articles/references-cited-in-idem-et-al-et-seq-id-op-cit-passim,-etc./)

> apud
>   – (do latim junto a; in; Close of) cited by, as, second - Indicates the source of an indirect quotation.
>
> To cite an author – the researcher whose work had NO access – what is stated in a book to which the researcher HAD access, It is used to reference apud. Ex:
>
> (ANDERSON, 1981 apud ARÉVALO, 1997, p. 73)
>
> ***In this example, by noting the word apud, soon we found that the author had no access to the director of the Anderson work, 1981. However, We had access to it through the work written by Arévalo, 1997.*** See more two examples:
>
> Studies Zapeda (apud MELO, 1995, p. 5) show […]
>
> BUTERA apud MONTEIRO, Washington de Barros. Course civil law: inheritance law. 30. and. Sao Paulo: Hail, 1995, in. 6, p. 80.
>
> ***It is recommended not really use the word apud throughout their work, restricting its use only to situations involving works hard to reach, eg: texts difficult to understand languages, rare books and antique items.***
>
> OBS: The phrase cited is the one that can be used in the text and notes. The remaining, only notes.

[Here's a further explanation from Charlton T. Lewis, An Elementary Latin Dictionary](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=apud)

Comment: Honestly, even if I had known the word _apud_ before seeing this question, I would most likely have written my citations as "Smith, 1945, _as cited in_ Jones, 1953", and noted that _Smith_ was not directly available to me.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, I appreciate your comment here.

Comment: Is this just quoting a blog, of questionable provenance?

Comment: The English usage (and formatting) in the quoted text is very stilted and difficult to understand; it would appear that the author of the blog is not a native English speaker.

Comment: Entirely correct. This is a typical usage of the word *apud* in the classics studies, where I see it often to mean "as quoted in". But I've never seen it used elsewhere.

Answer (score -4):

Apud and Chez do not belong to English... When you use it, you are speaking informal language.

Comment: _Au contraire_... the word _apud_ is not used in informal language, but in scholarly works only. And I would argue that any word that is used in a language belongs to it. Even if it originates from another language.

Comment: @OliverMason I think it's a spelling mistake. The OP probably wanted to say "you are speaking *in* formal language"